# How to convert byteArray into bitmap image to show in an imageview in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code for this purpose in my app but it does nothing, and halts the application:

```
bmImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage2, 0, byteImage2.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then I suppose you draw the image too like this:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmImage, 0, 0, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 95, blob);
byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: still no use the application is still halting when load the imageview

Answer (score 0):

use below line to convert bytes into Bitmap, it is working for me.

```
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
```

you need to put above line outside of loop, as it takes Bytes Array and convert into Bitmap.

P.S. :- here imageData is bytes array of Image

Comment: why outside the loop ? my problem is i have to load image from server everytime the user click "next " so i have to put this inside the loop.  the only thing i received from server is the bytecode of the image